# calabash-android gives JAVA_HOME error

Tags: java, android, macos, configuration, calabash

I have the following configuration. It seems there is no problem but when I run calabash-android it gives the error:

```
~ calabash-android run ~/Projects/android-automation/app-debug.apk
Could not find an Android SDK please make sure it is installed.
You can read about how Calabash-Android is searching for an Android SDK and how you can help here:
https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md#prerequisites
```

my configuration as follows:

```
~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin /usr/local/Cellar/ /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Users/mesutgunes/Android/sdk/platform-tools /Users/mesutgunes/Android/sdk/tools
~
~ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/mesutgunes/Android/sdk
~
~ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0_45-b14/Contents/Home/bin/java
~
~ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
~
~ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
~
```

I am using OS X Yosemite, having this error after I guess an iOS update. It was fine before.

Answer (score 0):

Calabash-Android behaves a bit unexpected when searching for the Android SDK tools. It will not use the $ANDROID_HOME env variable if it does not contain the right executables in the right directories. You should ensure that the ANDROID SDK is downloaded from the official source, and that the directory `/Users/mesutgunes/Android/sdk` contains a folder `platform-tools/adb`. Use `run -v` to turn on verbose mode.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt fix my issu  <br/> ```~ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/mesutgunes/Android/android-sdk-macosx
~
~ calabash-android run -v ~/Projects/morhipo/android-automation/app-debug.apk
2015-07-13 16:41:02 - JDK found on PATH.
Could not find an Android SDK please make sure it is installed.
You can read about how Calabash-Android is searching for an Android SDK and how you can help here:
https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md#prerequisites```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading JDK to 1.7 solved my problem and java_home is as following:

```
set JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calabash-android setup is incomplete, kindly install Java SDK and Android SDK.

Java SDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Android SDK: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Step 1: Download and install java & android sdk.

Step 2: Set JAVA_HOME & ANDROID_HOME in the system variable.
(Full description here: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md)

Step 3: Add java bin folder & android bin foler to system variable 'PATH'

Then run,

```
calabash-android run yourfile.apk
```